# JSON Loader Model

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I would like to ask what is wrong in this code,
I want to load my model but it only shows black form.

```
var build = null;
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('PERSONALJS/Building_Meta.js', function (geometry,material)
    {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);
        build = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,materials);
        scene.add(build);
    });
```

Comment: It shows a black form?

Comment: yes sir.. just a plain black

Comment: Do you mean blank?

Comment: yes sir, there is no model at all

Comment: Any error messages in browser’s console? Do you have any light source in your scene? THREE.MultiMaterial is deprecated, use just an array of materials.

Comment: scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666));
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xdfebff, 1);
    light.position.set(50, 200, 100);
    light.position.multiplyScalar(1.3);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    var d = 300;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -d;
    light.shadow.camera.right = d;
    light.shadow.camera.top = d;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
    scene.add(light);

Comment: here's the light. uhmm there is a material also in my model

Comment: THREE.JSONLoader has been removed. this kind of error also in my Console.

Comment: I see, your right Mugen87, The Three.JSONLoader was removed. Thanks.